# Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Call was canceled by the message filter

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, solution-deployment

When I deploy my Sharepoint solution I got below error.

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Call was canceled by the message filter.(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010002 (RPC_E_CALL_CANCELED))
```

What could be the reason? I retarcted, cleaned, IISReset and all.

Comment: It actually complains an error in my JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like permission problem. Please verify few points:

1. Make sure VS2010 is running as Administrator
2. Make sure you are the local admin and having owner rights in SQL content DB.
3. Also check your permission in few local groups

Comment: PS  http://www.stuartroberts.net/index.php/2011/07/16/deploy-solution-claims-based-authentication-site/